# Gmail smtp configuration for Drupal 7

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, drupal-7

I want to send email in Drupal 7. So, does anyone know how to configure Gmail SMTP on Drupal 7?

Comment: see this link: http://drupalmodules.xyz/content/configuring-drupal-smtp-module-send-emails-gmail

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. Download [SMTP](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module and enable it.
2. Go to Admin > Configuration > SMTP authentication support and set the following values:

   - Turn on the module at the Install options fieldset at the top.
   - SMTP server settings:
   - smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
   - smtp backup server: leave blank.
   - smtp port: 465
   - use encrypted protocol: select "use SSL"
   - SMTP authentication:
   - Enter a valid Gmail email address and password.
   - Email options:
   - Set the same email address that you used at SMTP Authentication. Using a different account is called [Phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing)
   - Send test email: set an email to receive a sample email.
   - Enable debugging: yes.

3. Click on submit and verify that the email was submitted and that you received it. If not, read carefully the debug information at the top of the screen. Once satisfied, remember to deactivate the debug checkbox.

Comment: Exactly exact. Thanks so much, simply followed your instruction to setup. :)

Comment: I've found that you need to enable `Allow less secure apps:` and enable `Allow access to your Google account` as demonstrated [here](http://www.stevepolitodesign.com/blog/drupal-configure-smtp-module-work-gmail-updated). I also use port `587` and enable `Use TLS`.

Comment: After following these steps (carefully I think), I'm still seeing the msg ": SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host" in my site logs. I've tried both 465/SSL and 587/TLS. I've enabled less secure apps, done the captcha part. Strangely I had this working from my offline dev site after fiddling with my firewall a bit, but now that I've moved online (Namecheap), it stopped working. Any additional tips would be great.

Comment: Hi, Am able to receive test mail from SMTP, but when i try send email from my custom module its not working. It suddenly stopped sending mail, i did not change the code.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Download [SMTP](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module and enable it.

Step 2: Go to Admin > Configuration > System > SMTP authentication support and set the following [values](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287):

- Turn this module on or off: On.
- SMTP server settings:

  - smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
  - smtp backup server: leave blank.
  - smtp port: 465
  - use encrypted protocol: select "use SSL"
- SMTP authentication:

  - Enter a valid Gmail email address and password.
- Email options:

  - Set the same email address that you used at SMTP Authentication.
- Send test email: set an email to receive a sample email and to test whether the module is working.
- Enable debugging: yes.

Step 2a(Optional): [Allow Less Secure Apps Access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) which is here: http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Step 3: Click on Save and go to your inbox to check. If there is an testing email then it is fine.

Note: Your email address provided in your smpt setting MUST be the same like in your site information.

Comment: I've found that you also need to enable  `Allow access to your Google account` as demonstrated [here](http://www.stevepolitodesign.com/blog/drupal-configure-smtp-module-work-gmail-updated). To do this, go to [https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha), click `continue` and then send a test email at `admin/config/system/smtp`

Answer (score 3):

I hope [SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module will help you.

Comment: Beta doesn't mean it's not working. At least try it. Maybe bugs which there exists doesn't bother you.

Comment: This module is used by more than 40.000 registered websites (see the stats below the releases listing). That is a good rule of thumb to decide whether a module is or not stable.

Answer (score 2):

For me, just following the steps in [Juampy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120652/juampy)'s answer didn't work. The error "Unable to send mail. Contact site administrator." continued to display. Do the following first and then configure SMTP module as per his answer.

Before installing [SMTP](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) module, download [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net/) and extract it. Rename the folder as 'phpmailer' and copy the folder into module folder of SMTP module. Then, install the SMTP module.

An alternative configuration is as follows:

- smtp port: 587
- use encrypted protocol: select "use TLS"

Comment: Many thanks. 
For some reason, I also had to add `require_once('class.smtp.php');` on top of the `class.phpmailer.php` file, as it was not finding the SMTP class...

Answer (score 2):

This blog entry has some more up-to-date info:

http://www.stevepolitodesign.com/blog/drupal-configure-smtp-module-work-gmail-updated

**Install and set-up module:**

1. Install the SMTP Authentication Support module in the usual way.
2. Navigate to the configuration page `admin/config/system/smtp`
3. Under Turn this module on or off select On. You can leave Send mail
   by queue and Retry sending mail on error. deselected by default, but
   selecting them won't affect Gmail.
4. Under SMTP server enter the following smtp.gmail.com. Leave SMTP
   backup server blank
5. Under SMTP port enter 587 ​
6. Under Use encrypted protocol select Use TLS ​
7. Under SMTP AUTHENTICATION enter a Gmail address and password.
8. Under E-MAIL OPTIONS use the same Gmail address as you did above and
   enter an E-mail from name
9. Click Save

**Update gmail account settings:**

1. Login to your Gmail account at https://myaccount.google.com/
2. On the account homepage, click Sign-in & security or navigate to https://myaccount.google.com/security
3. Scroll down to the Allow less secure apps: widget, and have it enabled.
4. Now navigate to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click Continue
5. Go back to the SMTP configuration page `admin/config/system/smtp`
6. Enter an email address you would like to receive a test message from and click Save configuration
7. Check your inbox to confirm you received the test message.