# Drupal 7, SMTP module + Gmail

Tags: configuration, drupal-7, smtp, gmail

Gmail blocks any suspicious activity, and kudos to them for that. An example of this is when you're configuring your SMTP module to use your gmail account for sending mail from your drupal 7 + SMTP module-enabled site. How do I enable gmail to accept mail from my Drupal site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I use to allow Drupal + SMTP access to my gmail's SMTP server:

1. **Note:** disabling the "overlay" module may help with reading the output generated in step #6; so consider disabling it.
2. Install and configure the SMTP module for drupal. Configure for your gmail account. Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782010/479709)
3. Prepare gmail to "watch" for new application access to your account.

   1. Ensure that you've logged in to gmail using the same account with which you wish to associate your Drupal site
   2. Visit https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
   3. You will be see instructions about how to enable another application to send on your behalf. You have 10 minutes after clicking **[ continue ]** to complete the next step.
4. The last field at admin/config/system/smtp is "SEND TEST E-MAIL" *which doubles as an excellent SMTP debugger, btw*. Enter your email address here and check **enable debuging** just below the field.
5. Click **[ Save Configuration  ]** this will trigger the sending of the test email.
6. Watch the debugging output produced by SMTP, which the SMTP module places visually towards the top of the SMTP configuration page.
7. If you see send errors, review the output for corrective actions.

Hope this helps.